# how to bind to `MouseArea`'s `onDragChanged`?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

Qt Creator suggests that the `onDragChanged` slot exists in `MouseArea`.

```
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        ...
        onDragChanged: console.log('Drag changed')
    }
```

But at runtime it fails with:

> Cannot assign to non-existent property "onDragChanged"

Comment: Where did you read in the docs about `onDragChanged`? I don't see that anywhere in the  MouseArea [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html).

Comment: MouseArea's `drag` is a group of properties, so you need to be more specific when trying to bind to one. Your answer below binds to `drag.active` which works because it is choosing one of the properties within `drag`.

Comment: `onDragChanged` shows up in QtCreator's completion. Properties such as `onDragActiveChanged` also don't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way would be:

```
drag.onActiveChanged: console.log("Drag active:", drag.active)
```

This is because `drag` is a group of properties (under the hood it's a QObject or alike), so you need to reference that group first.

Your initial attempt doesn't work because `drag` is declared as CONSTANT Q_PROPERTY, which doesn't have a `on...Changed` signal

Answer (score 0):

Silly workaround (but it works...)

```
readonly property bool _dragActive: drag.active
on_DragActiveChanged: {
    ... = drag.active
}
```